# How can I add a message after a post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an authentication form with the function `OnPostAsync()` and I want to add an error message when the authentication failed, but I can't get any message in my page.

I use and set a variable when I get the answer from the API, but the front code won't be update.

---

**Login.cshtml.cs**

```
public string errorMessage { get; set; }

public async void OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return;
    }

    var resp = await _loginService.Connection(user);

    if (resp == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("resp null");
        errorMessage = "Incorrect username or password";
        return;
    }
    _cookieService.Set("token", resp);
}
```

**Login.cshtml**

```
<div class="classbody">
    <form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Connexion</h1>
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" asp-for="user.Username" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" asp-for="user.Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Connexion</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
        @if (@Model.errorMessage != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                @Model.errorMessage
            </div>
        }
    </form>
</div>
```

The `errorMessage = "Incorrect username or password";` doesn't work after the await, if I put the line in the begin on the function (`OnPostAsync`), it works well but I need it after the API answer.

Comment: Is this webforms using Razor?

Comment: Yes it is, I didn't paste all code, juste a few blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Task instead of void.

Answer (score 1):

WhoKnows solved it, this is my code now and it works like a charm.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            var resp = await _loginService.Connection(user);
            if (resp == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("resp null");
                errorMessage = "Error";
                return Page();
            }
            return RedirectToPage("/Book");
        }
```